# What if difficulty exceeds the length of a fixed sha256 hash in proof of work?

Tags: go-ethereum, bitcoin, nonce, proof-of-work, difficulty

Hello im a newbie in Blockchain, i got to know some basics, but im confused that what if the difficulty exceeds the length of a sha256 fixed length string
example :

The fixed length is here 64 (sha256)
And the difficulty is 65
But how can we calculate them, for the specific block to be mined requires 65 zeros but the length is only 64, in this case what is applied, and if im wrong correct me?

Comment: If you can mine a block with an all-0 hash, you may win the Turing prize

Answer (score 2):

The length of a SHA256 hash is 256 bits: **2^256**.  The difficulty won't reach such a massive massive number.

> This number is bigger than the number of atoms in the perceivable
> universe. And not by just a little bit either. Exponentially bigger.
> This number is so big that the human mind can’t comprehend how big it
> is.

[Source](https://privacycanada.net/cryptanalysis/why-is-2-256-secure/)